# Does the create method on a one-to-one relationship in laravel create a second entry? (Laravel 5.6, mysql)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a one to one relationship, some users should get a code, which is a separate model.

However, when i call the create method 2 times, a second code is created and the first one is not deleted.

In my user-Model:

```
public function code() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Code');
}
```

In my code-model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In my migration file

```
Schema::table('codes', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->after('id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

So now, what i do is call the create method on the code-relation two times:

```
$user->code()->create([
        'code' => 'flower'
    ]);
$user->code()->create([
        'code' => 'computer'
    ]);
//Now in my database, there are 2 code entries with the userid, one with computer and one with flower
```

Of course, since it is a one-to-one relationship, I wanted the first code to be deleted, when the second one is created!
Is this the common behaviour of Laravel or am I making something wrong? Do I have to delete the code everytime i want to save a new one?

Comment: The behavior is correct, as documentation states. If you want to *alter* the relationship model, you may want to use the `update` method (there is also `updateOrCreate`). Otherwise you need to delete the old record.

Comment: Did you try `save` instead of create() ?

Comment: @alariva thanks for your answer! When i user the updateOrCreate method, ofc the code is not changed, because the new code is a different one. So using that, i also end up having two codes.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad thanks for the suggestion, the save method also leaves the first code attached :(

Comment: @DonFattie it actually depends on what are you *logically* willing to do, are you updating info? are you replacing models? For using an upadte, you need at least one key to identify the model (row) you want to touch. Unless you do that, the framework will interpret you are willing to add. As per your description, I believe you should delete and create as you are kind of replacing models. You may also unlink and create linked. But it's up to you depending on what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: @alariva yeah, seems like i need to do that :/ I was hoping there is a solution to delete the existing attached model and create a new one in one step!

Comment: @DonFattie if you think create() method will delete old record then you will never be able to make second record. Think it carefully

Comment: @AfrazAhmad i know, that is actually what i want to have since it is a one-to-one relationship! 
Still thanks for the help :) I ended up just writing $user->code()->delete; $user->code()->create(...);
Thanks again to both of you, really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is delete and create a new code in one step, this is a way to go around:

```
// in User model
public function replaceCode($codeName)

    $this->code()->delete();
    $this->code()->create([
            'code' => $codeName
        ]);

    return $this;
}
```

Note that other possible approaches (similar, but not identical) are unlink and create, or update, according to what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! I will use exactly that method, works just fine.

Comment: Sure, take it as a way to find out what you really need. Let room for further refactor.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get around this is to use a variable combined with the `->save()` method:

```
if(!$user->code){
  $code = new Code();
  $code->user_id = $user->id;
} else {
  $code = $user->code;
}

$code->code = "Flower";
$code->save();
```

This wouldn't delete and replace the existing code for your User, but would rather update it. Depends on if you want `$code->id` to change or not.